# Daytona in Windows Azure as a service?

Tags: azure

Does Windows Azure service contains a service for clients to use MapReduce? For example, a cloud service that already has installed a MapReduce framework (Daytona) that a client can buy to use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows Azure currently allows you to use MapReduce in Hadoop but at the moment this is a private developer preview. If you are interested you can always try to register here:

https://www.hadooponazure.com/

Benjamin wrote a blog post that describes how he used the developer preview to analyse over 1TB of IIS logs. Read this blog post to see Hadoop on Azure even if you don't have access to the preview: [Analyzing 1 TB of IIS logs with Hadoop Map/Reduce on Azure with JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2012/02/09/analyzing-1-tb-of-iis-logs-with-hadoop-map-reduce-on-azure-with-javascript-analyse-d-1-to-de-journaux-iis-avec-hadoop-map-reduce-en-javascript.aspx)